# Custom combobox with drawn images into datagrid view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I new to this custom datagridview column mechanism.  I'm want to have a combobox in a datagridview which will allow the user to pick different line styles (using DashStyle).  Tutorials i've found are either not for comboboxes or don't use drawing.

I can already make a working custom standalone ComboBox by overriding the OnDrawItem(), using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891214/c-sharp-combobox-with-lines)

But i am having trouble making a custom datagridview combobox column.

1. I want the comboboxcell's value to return a DashStyle.
2. I am also having trouble with displaying the drawn item at the form load.  Setting the default startup value to Dashstyle.Solid writes "Solid" in the combobox.  When i click in it it will trigger the draw item...

Here is the code i have so far, based on other examples on the web :

```
public class CustomComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
  public CustomComboBoxColumn()
  {
    CustomComboBoxCell cbc = new CustomComboBoxCell();
    this.CellTemplate = cbc;
  }
}

public class CustomComboBoxCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
{
  public CustomComboBoxCell()
  : base() { }

  public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
  {
    base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

    var ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as CustomComboBoxControl;

    if (this.Value == null)
      ctl.SelectedIndex = 0;
  }

  public override Type EditType
  {
    get { return typeof(CustomComboBoxControl); }
  }

  public override Type ValueType
  {
    get { return typeof(DashStyle); }
  }

  public override object DefaultNewRowValue
  {
    get { return DashStyle.Solid; }
  }

}


public class CustomComboBoxControl : MyComboBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
  private int index_ = 0;
  private DataGridView dataGridView_ = null;
  private bool valueChanged_ = false;

  public CustomComboBoxControl() : base()
  {
    this.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBoxControl_SelectedIndexChanged);
    this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
    this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
  }


  public void ComboBoxControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    NotifyDataGridViewOfValueChange();
  }


  protected virtual void NotifyDataGridViewOfValueChange()
  {
    this.valueChanged_ = true;
    if (this.dataGridView_ != null)
    {
      this.dataGridView_.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    }
  }

  public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle) {      }

  public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
  {
    get { return dataGridView_; }
    set { dataGridView_ = value; }
  }

  public object EditingControlFormattedValue
  {
    get { return base.SelectedValue; }
    set { base.SelectedValue = value; NotifyDataGridViewOfValueChange(); }
  }

  public int EditingControlRowIndex
  {
    get { return index_; }
    set { index_ = value; }
  }

  public bool EditingControlValueChanged
  {
    get { return valueChanged_; }
    set { valueChanged_ = value; }
  }

  public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
  {
    if (keyData == Keys.Return)
      return true;
    switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
    {
      case Keys.Up:
      case Keys.Down:
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }

  public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
  {
    get { return base.Cursor; }
  }

  public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
  {
    var val = EditingControlFormattedValue;
    if (val == null)
      val = DashStyle.Solid;
    return val.ToString();
  }

  public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll) { }

  public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
  {
    get { return false; }
  }

}
```

I appreciate any information about what i'm doing wrong and how this works...

Answer (score 0):

create a method which take the string "solid" and returns the DashStyle.Solid

```
private DashStyle GetDashStyle(string style){
  switch(style)
   {
        case "Solid":
         return DashStyle.Solid;
   }
}
```